# Leaderboard in MySQL - multiple "best" results are returned for each user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with a specific scenario in the implementation of a leaderboard in MySQL.

I have a table of users and posts, with each post having the number of awarded points. Posts can be in multiple categories (*activityUid* and *activityType*). The leaderboard is ranked based on the best post made by each user per category.

Because awarded points are not unique (multiple posts of user X in category Y may get the same number of points), I run into a situation where my query no longer returned the best post per each user but multiple posts with the same number of max points.

I'd like to narrow down the results to the **most recent** post (*dateCreated*) per user in case of a duplicate number of points.

Query:

```
SELECT main.*, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM (
    SELECT users.userUid, posts.postUid, posts.points, posts.dateCreated 
    FROM users 
    INNER JOIN posts ON users.userUid = posts.userUid 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT userUid, max(points) AS maxPoints 
        FROM posts 
        WHERE isLift = 1 AND verified = 1 AND activityUid = 'OP0iEbpmP36fkJdMTL2S' AND activityType = 'MAX_WEIGHT' 
        GROUP BY userUid 
        ORDER BY maxPoints DESC
    ) AS maxPerUser ON users.userUid = maxPerUser.userUid AND posts.points = maxPerUser.maxPoints 
    WHERE isLift = 1 AND verified= 1 AND activityUid = 'OP0iEbpmP36fkJdMTL2S' AND activityType = 'MAX_WEIGHT' 
    ORDER BY maxPerUser.maxPoints DESC, posts.dateCreated DESC
) AS main 
JOIN (SELECT @curRank:= 0) r 
ORDER BY rank ASC;
```

Output:

```
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+------+
|           userUid            |               postUid                | points |     dateCreated     | rank |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+------+
| RRyUFdaXsEO6DJOJDL8u7gu1aZ13 | cf6f54d0-336a-11e8-847c-2f396385505a |    303 | 2018-03-29 16:04:21 |    1 |
| jkLbDkRkaoUG4A851VjiEdWnNN32 | 8ada4110-3336-11e8-baaa-1755b4dadd4d |    302 | 2018-03-29 09:50:12 |    2 |
| jkLbDkRkaoUG4A851VjiEdWnNN32 | 4bee45d0-31ad-11e8-8072-2b86c9f79738 |    302 | 2018-03-27 10:55:06 |    3 |
| jkLbDkRkaoUG4A851VjiEdWnNN32 | 2fec75e0-31a9-11e8-8072-2b86c9f79738 |    302 | 2018-03-27 10:25:40 |    4 |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+------+
```

Desired results:

```
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+------+
|           userUid            |               postUid                | points |     dateCreated     | rank |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+------+
| RRyUFdaXsEO6DJOJDL8u7gu1aZ13 | cf6f54d0-336a-11e8-847c-2f396385505a |    303 | 2018-03-29 16:04:21 |    1 |
| jkLbDkRkaoUG4A851VjiEdWnNN32 | 8ada4110-3336-11e8-baaa-1755b4dadd4d |    302 | 2018-03-29 09:50:12 |    2 |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+------+
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to achieve the described functionality? Thanks!

---

Table schema (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userUid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userUid` (`userUid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=71 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `postUid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `isLift` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `userUid` varchar(48) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `activityUid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `activityType` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `points` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateCreated` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `postUid` (`postUid`),
  KEY `userUid` (`userUid`),
  KEY `isLift` (`isLift`),
  KEY `activityUid` (`activityUid`),
  KEY `activityType` (`activityType`),
  KEY `points` (`points`),
  KEY `dateCreated` (`dateCreated`),
  KEY `verified` (`verified`),
  CONSTRAINT `posts_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userUid`) REFERENCES `users` (`userUid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=862 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

Example dataset:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `userUid`)
VALUES
    (1, 'jkLbDkRkaoUG4A851VjiEdWnNN32'),
    (2, 'RRyUFdaXsEO6DJOJDL8u7gu1aZ13');

INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`, `postUid`, `isLift`, `userUid`, `activityUid`, `activityType`, `points`, `verified`, `dateCreated`)
VALUES
  (1,   '4adcc1b0-1e18-11e8-abc6-2f6e24661429', 1, 'jkLbDkRkaoUG4A851VjiEdWnNN32', 'OP0iEbpmP36fkJdMTL2S', 'MAX_WEIGHT', 30, 1, '2018-03-02 12:51:44'),
  (2,   '2fec75e0-31a9-11e8-8072-2b86c9f79738', 1, 'jkLbDkRkaoUG4A851VjiEdWnNN32', 'OP0iEbpmP36fkJdMTL2S', 'MAX_WEIGHT', 302, 1, '2018-03-27 10:25:40'),
  (3,   '4bee45d0-31ad-11e8-8072-2b86c9f79738', 1, 'jkLbDkRkaoUG4A851VjiEdWnNN32', 'OP0iEbpmP36fkJdMTL2S', 'MAX_WEIGHT', 302, 1, '2018-03-27 10:55:06'),
  (4,   '61bf2ee0-3272-11e8-bc76-611e04d7551e', 1, 'jkLbDkRkaoUG4A851VjiEdWnNN32', 'OP0iEbpmP36fkJdMTL2S', 'MAX_WEIGHT', 56, 1, '2018-03-28 10:25:57'),
  (5,   '8ada4110-3336-11e8-baaa-1755b4dadd4d', 1, 'jkLbDkRkaoUG4A851VjiEdWnNN32', 'OP0iEbpmP36fkJdMTL2S', 'MAX_WEIGHT', 302, 1, '2018-03-29 09:50:12'),
  (6,   'cf6f54d0-336a-11e8-847c-2f396385505a', 1, 'RRyUFdaXsEO6DJOJDL8u7gu1aZ13', 'OP0iEbpmP36fkJdMTL2S', 'MAX_WEIGHT', 303, 1, '2018-03-29 16:04:21');
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a597ce/5/0)

Comment: Well it's known a INNER JOIN will match multiple times if the match can be made. if you only could include some insert's with example data that matches your desired results.

Comment: Inserts included @RaymondNijland, thanks for checking out.

Comment: it's a good question @K0ff33 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace table `posts` with a query to extract the most recent post (dateCreated) of each `UserUid`/`Points`.

```
SELECT main.*, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM (
    SELECT users.userUid, posts.postUid, posts.points, posts.dateCreated 
    FROM users 
    INNER JOIN (select * from
                posts p where datecreated = (select max(datecreated)
                                             from posts where posts.userUid = p.userUid
                                                        and posts.points = p.points)
                ) posts ON users.userUid = posts.userUid 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT userUid, max(points) AS maxPoints 
        FROM posts 
        WHERE isLift = 1 AND verified = 1 AND activityUid = 'OP0iEbpmP36fkJdMTL2S' AND activityType = 'MAX_WEIGHT' 
        GROUP BY userUid 
        ORDER BY maxPoints DESC
    ) AS maxPerUser ON users.userUid = maxPerUser.userUid AND posts.points = maxPerUser.maxPoints 
    WHERE isLift = 1 AND verified= 1 AND activityUid = 'OP0iEbpmP36fkJdMTL2S' AND activityType = 'MAX_WEIGHT' 
    ORDER BY maxPerUser.maxPoints DESC, posts.dateCreated DESC
) AS main 
JOIN (SELECT @curRank:= 0) r 
ORDER BY rank ASC;
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a597ce/4)